# build opencv 4.5.0 with extra modules for java

Tags: java, opencv, cmake, visual-studio-2013

Trying to build OpenCV with extra modules for Java, to get the face module. I am getting the `.jar` file but I am not able to get the `.dll` one.

when trying to build using VS2013 I got lot of errors such as

C:\Users\Mini\Downloads\opencv-4.5.0\opencv-4.5.0\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/ocl.hpp(739): error C2610: 'cv::ocl::OpenCLExecutionContext::OpenCLExecutionContext(cv::ocl::OpenCLExecutionContext &&)' : n'est pas une fonction membre spéciale qui peut être définie par défaut (C:\Users\Mini\Downloads\opencv-4.5.0\opencv-4.5.0\modules\imgproc\src\resize.sse4_1.cpp)

maybe the problem is in cmake I don't know what to check and what to uncheck , please if someone could help me in that issue
Here is my `cmake` result:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            C:/Users/Mini/Downloads/opencv_contrib-4.5.0/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2020-12-03T15:40:01Z
    Host:                        Windows 6.1.7601 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.19.1
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 12 2013
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1800

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 18.0.21005.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          ade wsock32 comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
    3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf zlib libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf quirc

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform java line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    python_bindings_generator python_tests world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 alphamat cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype hdf js julia matlab ovis python2 python3 sfm viz
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.5-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.3.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    GDCM:                        NO
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.91.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.45.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.51.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.7.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/Users/Mini/Downloads/opencv-4.5.0/opencv-4.5.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            C:/Users/Mini/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe

  Java:                          export all functions
    ant:                         C:/apache-ant-1.10.9-bin/apache-ant-1.10.9/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.10.9)
    JNI:                         C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk-15/include C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk-15/include/win32 C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk-15/include
    Java wrappers:               YES
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/Users/Mini/Downloads/newbuild3/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
Generating done
```

Comment: The list `To be built:` contains `face`, so it is expected to be built when you build the project. So, do you have some errors during this build? Or, is the build successfull, but you cannot find corresponding `.dll` file?

Comment: @Tsyvarev No the build was unsuccessfull in visual studio,
It said that there're some syntax errors in cpp files don't know why, although those errors,I find the jar file opencv_450.jar  and library file for each module but the  huge library opencv_java450.dll is missing

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have a question please , if someone had already built open cv with extra modules successfuly and sent me the built folder .zip ,will it work on my system! if yes could you do it cuz don't have much time it's an academic project and time is wasted in installation in vain

Comment: No, I have no environment for build OpenCV. "the build was unsuccessfull in visual studio, It said that there're some syntax errors in cpp files ..." - Please, add this information (and exact error message) into the **question post**, so it would describe your problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev post edited do I haveto uncheck some checkboxesin cmake!